# What's wrong with this type alias

Tags: c++

A friend asked me to help with this, and I'm not sure what's going on.

```
namespace  
{  
   using TestString = const char* const;  

   TestString STRING = "This is a string";  
   TestString EDIT_STRING = "Try to modify string";  
}
```

"gpp -c" gives the following errors:

- test.cpp:3: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'TestString'
- test.cpp:3: error: 'TestString' has not been declared
- test.cpp:3: error: expected `;' before '=' token
- test.cpp:3: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
- test.cpp:5: error: 'TestString' does not name a type
- test.cpp:6: error: 'TestString' does not name a type

The errors after line 3 make sense...they can't work unti line 3 does,
and the bit on line 6 is expected to fail later in the test code.
But what's going on with line 3?

Also, where are these header files for C++?  I can't find them anywhere under
/usr/include (and definitely not IN /usr/include)?

- array
- inttypes
- unordered_map

Thanks

Comment: Are you compiling with C++11? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9f48681b8bd0354

Comment: what is wrong is that it is not legal until C++11. So compile it with C++11 or higher.

Comment: `gpp -c` - which compiler is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you have a compiler that does not support the C++ 2011 or you did not set on the option that allows the compiler to use the C++ Standard features.

Comment: Hmmmm, strange.  gcc-4.7.3 (2012) lacks C++ 2011 support?  I'll check the options in MacPorts.  Thanks.

Comment: @GTbrewer Usually each compiler can support only some features of the C++.

Comment: But that still leaves the other half of the question:  what about the header files I listed?  Is there another standard location aside from /usr/include these days that I don't know about?

Comment: @GTbrewer The headers should be in the same directory as other headers.

Comment: I checked...they aren't there.  Are these specific to C++ 2011?

Comment: @GTbrewer  It can be specific for a compiler,

Answer (score 0):

The answer above put me on the right track.  I did a google search on whether or not gcc-4.7.3
supports C++ 2011, and found another SO post with a little test program.  As it turns out, the support for C++ 2011 is experimental in that release, and must be specifically enabled.
Based on the grpes from gcc, it wasn't.  Time to upgrade now.

Thanks!